# jQuery.each - How to iterate over JSON objects element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, each

i am very new to play with JSON. I need to iterate over JSON response coming from AJAX, actually, i am fetching checkboxe values from db table in the form on 2,3,7,9,3. Now i am stuck with iteration on each number.

If you run following code in FF console area you will notice it is looping against each numeric NOT THE VALUE.

Please guide me.

```
var srv = {"services":"26,29"};

jQuery.each( srv.services, function(i, v) {
    console.log( v );
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.
THanks :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`srv.services` is a string of comma separated values, so `$.each()` won't work correctly.  You can [*split()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split) it into an array, though:

```
var srv = {"services":"26,29"};

jQuery.each(srv.services.split(","), function(i, v) {
    console.log( v );
});
```

**Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AndyE/veP4p/**

You could also have your JSON service return an array instead of a string, e.g. `{"services":[26, 29]}`.  This would be done for you automatically at the server if you're using proper JSON-compliant methods to encode and if the data is an array.

Comment: +1 for suggesting changing the data format at the server level.

Comment: Thnak you very much,Andy. you gave me a good concept about JSON.

Answer (score 1):

it is not valid json array, your json data should be something like this:

```
var srv = {"services": ["26", "29"]};
```

..or of-cause you could split your string data using js split function:

```
jQuery.each(srv.services.split(","), function(i, v) {
    console.log( v );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is an answer to your problem but given the declaration from above, try splitting on `,` before iterating:

```
var srv = {"services":"26,29"};

jQuery.each( srv.services.split(','), function(i, v) {
    console.log( v );
});
```

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/Y9gQy/))

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an array first

```
var srv = {"services":"26,29".split(",")};

jQuery.each( srv.services, function(i, v) {
    console.log( v );
});
```